# A system error occurred (EROFS: read-only file system

Tags: 16.04, ftp, xampp

I launched XAMPP on my PC with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. And Proftdp  launched too. I can connect to my server but I can't save changes and in files and can't upload new files too. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is it an NTFS filesystem? How is it mounted? look at `mount | grep /Volumes/maflic\.ru-`. Read `man mount`, and do something like `sudo mount -o remount,rw ...`